# Performance difference for fetching lon/lat from geography vs longitude and latitude fields

Tags: postgresql, postgis

What performs better?

I have a table containing:

```
id BIGSERIAL,
geog GEOGRAPHY,
longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
area GEOGRAPHY
```

`geog` is generated by `ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)`. I can extract the longitude and latitude from `geog` with `ST_X` and `ST_Y` when I need them, but I don't know if simply recording the longitude and latitude for reuse and query is better for performance.

`geog` and `area` are for calculating results like items within, nearest, overlaps, etc. Client typically just need a filtered list of items and the lon/lat.

---

After running some tests it looks like storing lon/lat is slightly faster (for my limited dataset). I ran it a few times and the results favors storing.

**Storing lon/lat**

```
explain analyze
  select
    longitude,
    latitude
  from location;

-- 'Seq Scan on location  (cost=0.00..3.04 rows=104 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.032 rows=104 loops=1)'
-- 'Planning time: 0.062 ms'
-- 'Execution time: 0.047 ms'
```

**Using ST_X & ST_Y**

```
explain analyze 
  select
    st_y(geog::geometry),
    st_x(geog::geometry)
  from location;

-- 'Seq Scan on location  (cost=0.00..4.08 rows=104 width=16) (actual time=0.026..0.192 rows=104 loops=1)'
-- 'Planning time: 0.064 ms'
-- 'Execution time: 0.224 ms'
```

Is there a faster alternative to ST_X and ST_Y? I think it would be rather common for people to need to grab longitude and latitude from a geography type.

Comment: I think you should be able to get an answer fairly easily by making a copy of your table and testing your theory. Having said that, if you are basically only querying for long/lat then using a conversion function on every query would have to be slower than just returning the float values right?

Comment: You could check with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.  Do a select of the lat/lon fields and compare that select with the lat/lon from `geog`

Comment: Thanks! It looks like storing lon/lat is a bit more performant when it comes to directly getting lon/lat.

Comment: It is good to considerate the amount of extra data vs the efficiency gain: if you need two extra columns on millions of rows to save less than a millisecond, it is really worth it? Also you  must consider whether the points will be updates (moved) or not, as the lat-long columns must be in synch with the geometry location

Comment: I believe @JacobH has a point: casting `geography` to `geometry` and then extracting _x_ and _y_ from them is more likely to be slower than simply reading a pair of double values. However, storing coordinates like this can be *very* tricky when you start dealing with multiple SRS (spatial reference systems). I would rather invest more time in indexing than downgrade my data model. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @JimJones and JGH, you do make a good point about dealing with multiple SRS. I was only commenting on the speed in particular.